# Grunt redirect rest call to file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am using `grunt` connect server with all those `livereload` plugins. Developing process was very fast till I added some rest calls. I decided to make some example `JSON` files which ll be rest calls answers.

So I need to **redirect** every rest call to some `static` folder(important I ll put it in target folder) so it ll be outside the **Angular** folder.

So I need some `plugin` which transfer calls like:

```
http.get(localhost:port/x/y/name) to target/jsons_examples/x/y/name.json
http.get(localhost:port/z/name) to target/jsons_examples/z/name.json
```

grunt file:(1 aplication server, 1 mocking webservices)

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
  all: {
    options: {
        port: 10100,
        hostname: "0.0.0.0",
        livereload: true
    }
  },
  webservices_mock: {
    options: {
        port: 8081,
        hostname: "0.0.0.0",
        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
            middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
                var pattern = new RegExp('\/rest\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/.]+', 'i'),
                    matches = req.url.match(pattern);

                if (!matches) {
                    return next();
                }

                req.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                res.write(grunt.file.read(req.url.replace("/rest", "json_contracts") + "/example.json"));

                res.end();
            });

            return middlewares;
        }
    }
  }
},
...
```

And now i need in web services mock configuration change the path from json_contracts to path outside angular folder smth like: ././././target/json_contracts

Comment: please add your grunt configuration

Comment: I added in my question. Anyway like I said its just begining so it is almost default config.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [middleware](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#middleware) option to inject your own URL parser. See the comments to understand how it works:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    all: {
      options:{
        port: 8080,
        base: dir_to_angular_main_folder
        hostname: "localhost",
        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
          middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
            // pattern is a RegExp which is going to find the redirected url
            var pattern = new RegExp('^/x/y/([0-9A-Z]+)$', 'i'),
                // matches is a result which is
                //  - undefined when no match found
                //  - an array with two values when found:
                //    0: the full string
                //    1: the string inside of the brackets (the file name)
                matches = req.url.match(pattern);

            // if your url does not match skip the bottom part
            if (!matches) return next();

            // this runs only if match is found, set up the redirect header
            // up to you to decide whether it is 301 or 302
            // I would keep it 302 for dev purposes (browsers won't cache it)
            res.writeHead(302, {
              Location: '/target/jsons_examples/x/y/' + matches[1] + '.json'
            });

            // send the response
            res.end();
          });

          return middlewares;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I guess you will still need to change the pattern to the one you need (x / y / target don't sound as real names).

One can say you can do it easier without matching like this `([0-9A-Z]+)` and using the matches here `'/target/jsons_examples/x/y/' + matches[1] + '.json'` and he will be right. It was made with a name only because it is more flexible, e.g. when you have a folder in between x and y etc. Anyway, as it was said before, you can also make it simpler and just use the following:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
  Location: '/target/jsons_examples' + req.url + '.json'
});
```

I could not test it, maybe it gives you some errors, but still I hope this is good enough to give an idea what and how to do.

**EDIT**

Well, according to the fact that your JSON files are not visible from the webserver side (the root folder is out of scope) you can do some kind of *url rewriting* instead of redirect:

```
var fs = require('fs');

grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    all: {
      options:{
        port: 8080,
        base: dir_to_angular_main_folder
        hostname: "localhost",
        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
          middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
            // pattern is a RegExp which is going to find the redirected url
            var pattern = new RegExp('^/x/y/([0-9A-Z]+)$', 'i'),
                // matches is a result which is
                //  - undefined when no match found
                //  - an array with two values when found:
                //    0: the full string
                //    1: the string inside of the brackets (the file name)
                matches = req.url.match(pattern);

            // if your url does not match skip the bottom part
            if (!matches) return next();

            // this runs only if match is found, set up the redirect header
            // reads the file content and sends as a response
            res.end(fs.readFileSync('/<some-absolute-path>/target/jsons_examples/x/y/' + matches[1] + '.json', 'utf8'));
          });

          return middlewares;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Note that you need to include the Nodejs standard `fs` module on the top of your Gruntfile to make it work. This is again just a prototype, change the paths according to your requirements. Maybe you would also need to write the mime-type as a header of your response, there are already many answers on how to do it in Node as well.

Comment: looks promising, but it not firing for http inside some js controllers. I added simple log console.log('req: ' + req.url) it shows call of my controller as 'app/testController.js' but inside I am using $http.get(<examples/user.json> or <localhost:8080/rest/getExampleJson>)
and middleware isn't firing for any of file or rest call

Comment: edit: $http.get(examples/user.json) for file it is firing but with prefix 'app/' but for rest noting firing.

Comment: could you for the sake of pure testing try with any of your files just calling in the browser _http://localhost:port/x/y/name_ and tell the result? This will exclude a probability of problems on Angular side, maybe it is not calling something or you have a `<base>` tag...

Comment: x is webservice class path @Path("/x"). y is webservice method path @Path("/y"). So the rest gonna be localhost:port/x/y. So in jsons project there is folder x/y/example.json. This project is unpacked to my angular project to target folder(not the src!). So calling localhost:port/x/y/name is reference to nothing. localhost:port/x/y is rest call, but I want to develop without rest calls. So I want to redirect all rest calls localhost:port/x/y to file in path /mydir/angularproject/target/x/y/example.json

Comment: I understand that, but still it also should be testable outside of Angular as simple as just calling the URL manually. What I mean if you call this URL it should also redirect you to the corresponding JSON. Does it happen?

Comment: No, problem is that I dont know how to write properly Location for target folder. When I type localhost:port/x/y/name it redirect me to localhost:port/target/x/y/example.json so it not giving nothing, we are still in angular folder. Instead of this redirection it should just return for me json from path /media/data/project/target/x/y/example.json

Comment: I ve added code in first post, which is close to solution, just dont know how to write location for target folder

Comment: ok, maybe now u ll help me I just replace path from rest to path to file. Problem is that webservices are on other machines/ports so this middleware isn't firing. Code in first post.

Comment: ok, I ve made it. I mocked the webservices server. So now only problem is that I replace rest call to file from angular folder while I need file from outside angular folder. So question is how to get file from any location.

Comment: @user2771738 added another version, see EDIT section

Comment: Ye, that's something what i looked for :) Anyway I get suggestion to use serve-static plugin. And serve some static folder instead those weird replace statement. Your solution is good, but the most elegance would be serve-static which I cannot implement (some syntax errors whole time).